# Leaflet: Uncaught TypeError: map._getNewTopLeftPoint is not a function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to follow the JSFiddle example on the link : 
http://jsfiddle.net/BeniBoy/aeas62mh/1/

But I keep getting on error :

```
  Uncaught TypeError: map._getNewTopLeftPoint is not a function
```

when I hover the sidebar or click onto the marker.

I am using pug and loading my script as

```
 script(src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js')
```

on the header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method was available until 0.7: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/0.7/src/map/Map.js#L740

It has been removed in 1.0 (which is the version you are using).

Note that, because it starts with an underscore, it was considered as private and should not have been used in the first place.

Comment: I am wondering how can I fix that but still using the new version?

Comment: The fiddle is just working on that fiddle webpage, not on mine. It shows me the same error.

Comment: And even when I click onto the marker, no popup shows up too.

Comment: You probably want to use `map.panTo(e.target.getLatLng());` instead of calculating the offset and then `map.panBy(offset)`.

Comment: Anyway, I use panTo(e.target.getLatLng()) and it shows me this: "Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined"

Comment: Make sure you use it in an event handler: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events